# Relationship between metric and normed spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

If $X=\mathbb{R}$ and  $d\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y)={\sqrt{|x-y|}}$, I am able to show that this is indeed a metric.

But what I don't understand is how this metric doesn't come from a norm, like how do I even define a norm on this metric? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$d(x,0)=\sqrt {|x|}.$$ Thus

$$d(\lambda x,0)=\sqrt{|\lambda|}\sqrt {|x|}\ne |\lambda| d(x,0)$$ if $|\lambda|\ne \pm 1$ and $x\ne 0.$ That is, $d$ is a metric but not comes from a norm.

Comment: In other words: this distance function does not obey the scalar multiplication rule that $\|\lambda x\| = |\lambda|\|x\|$ for scalars $\lambda$ and vectors $x\in X$.  (Only vector spaces may have norms.)

Comment: thanks so the norm of x is always d(x,0)?

Comment: also you mean x is not the zero vector right in the last line?

Comment: Any norm $\|\cdot \|$ defines a metric $d(\cdot , \cdot)$ and it is $\|x\|=d(x,0).$ And yes, I mean $x$ is not the zero vector.